# Xamarin.Android и правильная архитектура приложения

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Решил тут заняться изучением Xamarin.Android. И не могу найти "наставляющих" правильных инструкций по правильной организации типового приложения.

Как я успел увидеть, MVVM в дроиде не возможен в силу отсутствия байдинга, ну может тогда MVP?! Нет, тоже фигушки. Сколько посмотрел на ютубе уроков - все лепится, порой даже с написанием UI, прямо в класс `MainActivity`. Огромная простыня начиная с обработчика `OnCreate` и поехали: тут же создаем контент с вьюшками, тут же подписываемся на события, ниже пошли обработчики событий и проч. Прямо как у студентов первокурсников.

Может что подскажите по теме, обращаюсь особенно к тем, кто уже немало поработал с замарином. Спасибо.

Comment: Стандартный паттерн андроид - MVC, который реализует активити в роли контроллера (вью - разметка). Паттерн MVVM реализует библиотека Google - [data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) . Так же есть сторонние библиотеки, реализующие паттерн MVP. Насколько это совместимо с ксамарин мне неведомо.

Comment: @pavlofff ага, спасибо, а что вы скажете про [это](https://youtu.be/70WqJxymPr8?t=643)

Comment: @Bulson: А почему нету? Это не оно: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/ ?

Comment: @VladD это Forms, а не "нативная" разработка. Я их тоже попробовал 2 дня назад. Но огреб кучу проблем с невозможностью работы с DataTemplate в ListView - не компилится проект из-за несовместимости библиотек. Убираешь темплейт - компилится, а с ним нет.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну, хм, допустим не компилится. Но отказываться из-за этого от Xamarin.Forms и переходить на нативную часть, это ж всё равно что откатываться на WinForms, разве нет?

Comment: Вот представьте: читаете доку с замариновского сайта и пытаешься повторить пишешь `new NavigationPage(...)`, запускаешь...и...вываливается ошибка компиляции. Гуглишь... находишь, что гугл в последней версии изменил какой-то там... вообщем из-за это не работает навигация, нужно обновлять библиотеки. Идешь обновлять, и тут зависимости, самая последняя версия не хочешь работать с самой последней Xamarin.Forms библиотекой:) В итоге забарываешь как-то. Пишешь дальше и тут DataTemplate и снова похожая ошибка... В итоге я жирно плюнул на этот гемор.

Comment: Кроссплатформенная разработка вообще боль, а совместь iOS, android и winPhone и чтобы это изделие еще "выглядело" приемлемо на всех платформах из разряда существования сыра Хохланд, если кто то его еще помнит

Comment: @pavlofff "Гладко было на бумаге, да забыли про овраги." из этой оперы, да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Как я успел увидеть, MVVM в дроиде не возможен в силу отсутствия байдинга... 
Почему вы так решили? Для Xamarin Native к примеру есть MVVM Cross c поддержкой байдингов. Вся информация в блоге https://mvvmcross.com/blog.
Для xamarin forms можно использовать его же или FreshMvvm https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm (более легкий и работает как часы).
По ссылкам можно посмотреть примеры базовой конфигурации. Проекта.