# Xamarin.Android MVC или МVP что лучше? Как правильнее?

Tags: android, c#, mvc, xamarin, mvp

На ранее заданный  мной [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/598779/222542) в комментариях мне указали на то, что для андроида реализуют MVC. В интернетах я еще поизучал этот вопрос и выяснил, что `Activity`как бы совмещает в себе View и Controller сразу. Но есть так же и варианты с реализацией MVP, правда, все это было представлено вариантами на Java.Я решил вынести на ваш суд оба варианта одной элементарной проги, которая складывает два числа и выводит результат.

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, и оцените, что лучше выбрать:

**начнем с MVC**

*это модель (сложная такая)*

```
public class MainModel
{
    public int ResultAdd { get; private set; }

    public void AddTwoNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        ResultAdd = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
```

*это активити*

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    //Model
    private Model.MainModel _Model;

    //UI
    private TextView _FirstNumber;
    private TextView _SecondNumber;
    private TextView _Result;
    private Button _AddButton;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        //Model
        _Model = new Model.MainModel();

        //UI
        _FirstNumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextFirst);
        _SecondNumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextSecond);
        _Result = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewResult);
        _AddButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAdd);

        //Events
        _AddButton.Click += _AddButton_Click;

    }

    private void _AddButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int fn = int.Parse(_FirstNumber.Text);
        int sn = int.Parse(_SecondNumber.Text);

        //сложение
        _Model.AddTwoNumbers(fn, sn);

        //выводим результат
        _Result.Text = _Model.ResultAdd.ToString();
    }
}
```

**теперь MVP**
модель такая же

*а это Presenter*

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    //все что нам нужно от интерфейса
    public interface IView
    {
        string FirstNumber { get; }
        string SecondNumber { get; }
        string ResultNumber { get; set; }

        event EventHandler AddEvent;
    }

    //экземпляр интерфейса
    private IView _View;
    //Model
    private MainModel _Model;

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IView view)
    {
        _View = view;
        //подписываемся на событие
        _View.AddEvent += _View_AddEvent;

        _Model = new MainModel();
    }

    private void _View_AddEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fn = int.Parse(_View.FirstNumber);
        int sn = int.Parse(_View.SecondNumber);

        //обращаемся к модели за результатом
        _Model.AddTwoNumbers(fn, sn);

        //выводим результат
        _View.ResultNumber = _Model.ResultAdd.ToString();
    }
}
```

*это активити*

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, MainPresenter.IView
{
    //Presenter
    private MainPresenter _Presenter;

    //IView
    public string FirstNumber
    {
        get { return FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextFirst).Text; }
    }

    public string SecondNumber
    {
        get { return FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextSecond).Text; }
    }

    public string ResultNumber
    {
        get { return FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewResult).Text; }

        set { FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewResult).Text = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler AddEvent = delegate { };

    //запуск
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        //Presenter
        _Presenter = new MainPresenter(this);

        //Events
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAdd).Click +=
                        (s, e) => { AddEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
    }
}
```

Мне больше нравится MVP. Но смущает, то что "запускать" `Presenter` приходится из `Activity`. А надо бы из `Main()`, чтобы View не был связан с `Presenter`. Но, как я понял, у программ для дроида, как бы нет такого метода, а стартует `Activity` обозначенная в манифесте как `MainLauncher`, да еще и в случае переворота экрана происходит перезапуск последней активной активити. 
Что скажите на сей счет?

Comment: По идее презентер можно сделать синглтоном и, если надо, уведомлять его о вызовах методов жизненного цикла активити. Инициализировать можно при первом создании активити или при вызове onCreate класса Application- аналог main

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за идею.